# Start activity of another task and stay within current task

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, android-task

I have an application with, let say, two activities. One of the activity is already launched and after pressing "home" button it is in background. Now, from the ANOTHER application the second activity is launched. And when this second activity is finished I got to the first launched activity, not in the application that started the second activity. Is it normal behaviour? If it is, is there some way to change it? I need to stay in the application that launches the second activity, and not in the application which this second activity from.